# In which US states are Catholic dioceses being investigated for Sexual Abuse?

Tags: catholicism, politics, sexual-abuse-scandals

I recently read something in my parish’s bulletin saying that our diocese was getting investigated by the Attorney General for sex abuse.

> With this announcement, Wisconsin will join at least 22 other states that have launched investigations into sexual abuse by Catholic clergy and others in position of leadership.
>
> https://www.catholicworldreport.com/2021/04/23/wisconsin-attorney-general-to-investigate-sex-abuse-by-catholic-clerics/

But I can't find a list of which states are getting investigated currently.

Are there new allegations of sexual abuse that Catholics should know about or is this just the same stories as before being rehashed?

Answer (score 2):

**In which US states are Catholic dioceses being investigated for Sexual Abuse?**

> [With this announcement, Wisconsin will join at least 22 other states that have launched investigations into sexual abuse by Catholic clergy and others in position of leadership.](https://www.catholicworldreport.com/2021/04/23/wisconsin-attorney-general-to-investigate-sex-abuse-by-catholic-clerics/)

Here are the states which I have been able to narrow down as to date (officially investigations only):

1. California
2. Colorado
3. Delaware
4. Florida
5. Georgia
6. Illinois
7. Indiana
8. Iowa
9. Kansas
10. Maryland
11. Massachusetts
12. Michigan
13. Missouri
14. New Jersey
15. New Mexico
16. New York
17. Pennsylvania
18. Rhode Island
19. Vermont
20. Virginia
21. Washington, DC
22. West Virginia

This list was compiled with the following articles:

- [22 State AGs Investigating Sexual Abuse in the Catholic Church](https://childusa.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/2020-05-04-State-AGs-Investigating-Sexual-Abuse-in-Catholic-Church.pdf)
- [Even more states have launched investigations into clerical abuse since the Pennsylvania report](https://www.vox.com/2018/9/17/17847466/state-investigations-clerical-abuse-dc-virginia-maryland-florida-new-york)
- [Trail of Abuse Leads to Seminary](https://www.latimes.com/archives/la-xpm-2005-nov-17-me-stjohns17-story.html)
- [Sexual abuse scandal in the Catholic archdiocese of Los Angeles](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexual_abuse_scandal_in_the_Catholic_archdiocese_of_Los_Angeles)
- [Legislature Considers Sex Abuse Investigation Of Catholic Church](https://www.civilbeat.org/2019/03/legislature-considers-sex-abuse-investigation-of-catholic-church/)